# Finding the mean with absolute value

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

This question is out of my field and topic that I am teaching myself now, but I was wondering how would you solve this problem if it had the absolute value of it.

My Question:

> $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
> 2/9(x-1),  & \text{for $1<x<4$} \\
> 0, & \text{elsewhere}  \\
> \end{cases}
> $$

I know what was given is $\mu=3$ and $\sigma=$ $\sqrt{.5}=.7071$

> I wanted to find $E[|x-\mu|]$.

My first thoughts would be $\int_1^4|x-\mu|f(x)dx.$ That is all I can think of because I did not learn about this one yet. I was just wondering out of curiousity how to solve this problem and seeing what it would look like. It seems like something good to know for later problems that are like it.

$\int_1^4|x-\mu|f(x)dx$

$=\int_1^3 (2/9)(x-1)(3-x)dx+\int_3^4 (2/9)(x-1)(x-3)dx$

$2/9\int_1^3(-x^2+4x-3)dx+2/9\int_3^4(x^2-4x+3)dx$

$2/9\int_1^3(-x^3/3+2x^2-3x) + 2/9\int_3^4 (x^3/3-2x^2+3x)$

$(2/9)(-x^3/3+2x^2-3x)|_1^3 + (2/9)(x^3/3-2x^2+3x)|_3^4$

$8/27+8/27$

$16/27$

Comment: Your first thought is correct. Knowing that $\mu=3$, you can simplty split the integral into two integrals; one from 0 to 3 and one from 3 to 4, and then utilizing that $|x-\mu|=\mu-x$ for $1<x<3$ and $|x-\mu|=x-\mu$ for $3<x<4$, since $\mu=3$.

Comment: I got that part, but I do not know how to solve it with the $x-\mu$ problem. It is kind of fustrating me since I was thinking about this problem for a while now.

Comment: What do you mean? You just need to find $\int_1^3 (3-x)\frac{2}{9} (x-1)\,\mathrm dx$ and $\int_3^4 (x-3)\frac29(x-1)\,\mathrm dx$ and add the two.

Comment: Sorry. I guess that is what happens when you think about a problem too much. ha. I will still try to solve it though. I would also still like to see an answer to verify my answer if that is ok.

Comment: Then you should post it as an answer here, and then I'd be happy to verify your answer.

Comment: Can someone please check my answer?

Comment: Looks good, @carson.

Comment: Is it possible to vote for my own answer. I was just thinking about that.

Comment: @StefanHansen Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_1^4|x-\mu|f(x)dx$

$=\int_1^3 (2/9)(x-1)(3-x)dx+\int_3^4 (2/9)(x-1)(x-3)dx$

$2/9\int_1^3(-x^2+4x-3)dx+2/9\int_3^4(x^2-4x+3)dx$

$2/9\int_1^3(-x^3/3+2x^2-3x) + 2/9\int_3^4 (x^3/3-2x^2+3x)$

$(2/9)(-x^3/3+2x^2-3x)|_1^3 + (2/9)(x^3/3-2x^2+3x)|_3^4$

$8/27+8/27$

$16/27$